# Connect edges crease problem

Tags: edges, faces

I am very begginer with blender, as you see when I press F to create faces it creates automaticly creases in that place only, in the upper part that I made before it made everything smooth, what am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you could have some vertices that share the same coordinate. Select your Mesh in Edit Mode and try Alt + M > "by Distance" to merge them.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem) !!
It was some faces inverted.
[image]